# PHP Combine Associative Arrays If Specific Key Matches Inside For-Loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am working to combine 2 different arrays based on the comparison of a key if the values match, otherwise the combine does not occur.

Here is a short example of each array to begin with, however both array could be about 1,000 items:

```
Vehicle Array
(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford Transit 250 Cargo Van
  [stockno] => 153721
  [msrp] => 32195
  [price] => 32195
  [payment] => 359
  [type] => New
  [bodystyle] => Van
  [mileage] => 6
  [year] => 2016
  [make] => Ford
  [model] => Transit 250
  [trim] => Cargo Van
),(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford F150 XLT
  [stockno] => 153723
  [msrp] => 36195
  [price] => 36195
  [payment] => 429
  [type] => New
  [bodystyle] => Truck
  [mileage] => 6
  [year] => 2016
  [make] => Ford
  [model] => F150
  [trim] => XLT
)

Special Array
(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford Transit 250 Cargo Van
  [store] => Baxter Ford
  [offertype] => $ Off MSRP
  [offervalue] => Up to $10,000
  [disclaimer] => *Valid on in-stock models. Based on stock #161621. Tax, title and license extra. With approved credit. Includes hail sale savings. See dealer for details. Offer expires 8\/1\/16.
  [expires] => 8/1/16
),(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford Mustang Premium
  [store] => Baxter Ford
  [offertype] => $ Off MSRP
  [offervalue] => Up to $4,000
  [disclaimer] => *Valid on in-stock models. Based on stock #163421. Tax, title and license extra. With approved credit. Includes hail sale savings. See dealer for details. Offer expires 8\/1\/16.
  [expires] => 8/1/16
)
```

The goal is to combine on Vehicle Array[vehicle] and Special Array[vehicle] to create an array like this:

```
Combined Array
(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford Transit 250 Cargo Van
  [stockno] => 153721
  [msrp] => 32195
  [price] => 32195
  [payment] => 359
  [type] => New
  [bodystyle] => Van
  [mileage] => 6
  [year] => 2016
  [make] => Ford
  [model] => Transit 250
  [trim] => Cargo Van
  [store] => Baxter Ford
  [offertype] => $ Off MSRP
  [offervalue] => Up to $10,000
  [disclaimer] => *Valid on in-stock models. Based on stock #161621. Tax, title and license extra. With approved credit. Includes hail sale savings. See dealer for details. Offer expires 8\/1\/16.
  [expires] => 8/1/16
),(
  [vehicle] => 2016 Ford F150 XLT
  [stockno] => 153723
  [msrp] => 36195
  [price] => 36195
  [payment] => 429
  [type] => New
  [bodystyle] => Truck
  [mileage] => 6
  [year] => 2016
  [make] => Ford
  [model] => F150
  [trim] => XLT
)
```

This seems extremely simple, but I seem to missing something. I have attempted this with a nested foreach like so:

```
foreach ($vehicleArr as $v) {
  foreach ($specialArr as $s) {
    if ($v['vehicle'] === $s['vehicle']) {
      $freshArr[] = array_merge($v, $s);
    } else {
      $freshArr[] = $v;
    }
  }
}
```

This creates a massive memory leak and kills the script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use `array_merge()` to merge just one array element.  You're sticking the entire contents of both input arrays into one element of the output array each time.

Comment: Since `array_merge()` won't work, what would be the alternative function to call?

Comment: Forget it, I'm wrong.  I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of your code: new array sizes becomes n*m length.

And my working example

```
$vehicleList = [
    [ 'vehicle' => '2016 Ford Transit 250 Cargo Van',
        'stockno' => '153721'],
    [ 'vehicle' => '2016 Ford F150 XLT',
        'stockno' => '153723']
];
$spectialList = [
    [ 'vehicle' => '2016 Ford Transit 250 Cargo Van',
        'store' => 'Baxter Ford'],
    [ 'vehicle' => '2016 Ford Mustang Premium',
        'store' => 'Baxter Ford']
];

$newVehicleList = $vehicleList;

// let's change new array using reference
foreach ($newVehicleList as &$vehicle) {
    foreach ($spectialList as $special) {
        if ($vehicle['vehicle'] == $special['vehicle']) {
            //just change value wihtout creationg new one
            $vehicle = array_merge($vehicle, $special); 
        }
    }
}
// to make sure that there will no be any changes
unset($vehicle); 

var_dump($newVehicleList);
```

About reference in foreach you could read there: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php